# Power BI - Matrix Count Blank Rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a matrix having data of salesman and their chemist visited.

[image]

I  have added a count formula

```
Customer Count = DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('Source Data'[CustomerNameFull])
```

The total in the above matrix is of the salesman who visited the chemist, along with that I want to calculate the total of chemist that is not visited by a salesman. i.e. the count of the blank. The blank count should be shown along with the total value.

Source File: [BI SAS](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rsn4jsw0dhang24g2wawc/BI-SAS.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=q7x2uyhinikcc4o79gq46ctsd)

**Expected Output**

Below is the expected output that I want. The zero total is the distinct count

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the expected result in place I propose the following measures. One to count the distinct unvisited chemists for the selected salesman/salesmen:

```
Unvisited Chemists := 
VAR _customerCount = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK ( 'Source Data'[CustomerNameFull] ) , ALLSELECTED ( Dates ) )
VAR _visitedCount = [Customer Count]
RETURN _customerCount - _visitedCount
```

And one to format the matrix:

```
Customer Count w/ Unvisited = 
IF ( [Customer Count] <> BLANK () ,
    SWITCH ( 
        TRUE (), 
        NOT ISINSCOPE ( 'Source Data'[CustomerNameFull] ) && ISINSCOPE ( Dates[Month] )  ,
        [Customer Count] & " (" & [Unvisited Chemists] & ")" ,
        FORMAT ( [Customer Count] , "#" )
    )
)
```

Please note that here I am using a date table instead of using auto date/time on the `INVDATE` column. This is considered best practice anyway. Remember to set the correct sort column, see guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column

I have used a simple date table:

```
Dates = 
ADDCOLUMNS ( 
    CALENDARAUTO () , 
    "Year" , YEAR ( [Date] ) ,
    "MonthNo" , MONTH ( [Date] ) ,
    "Month" , FORMAT ( [Date] , "MMMM" )
)
```

The data model looks like this:

[image: Data model]

The result looks like this:

[image: Resulting matrix visual]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It's still not getting me the desired result. I want to count the blanks per month against each user for each salesmans

Comment: And the blank count in matrix should be distinct

Comment: It is still a bit difficult to figure out what you want - maybe you could show the expected output. If you also want to count how many chemists have not been visited on salesman level, you can remove the `&& NOT ISINSCOPE ( 'Source Data[SalesmanName] )` clause in my suggestion.

Comment: The non-visited counts are not distinct as i guess?

Comment: The non-visited measure is a distinct count of all the values in `CustomerNameFull` minus the measure you supplied. That gives the distinct count of chemists that have not been visited, in a given filter context.

Comment: I have added my expected output. hope you will get the better idea now

Comment: Thank you! See my updated answer - perhaps this satisfies your requirement.

Comment: My output is different from yours. The "()" are  not there :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235322/discussion-between-moeez-and-marcus).

Comment: kindly check the chat

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69299604/6854117) related to power-bi?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
VAR AllChemists = 
    CALCULATETABLE ( 
        VALUES ( Table[Chemist] ), 
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Table[Chemist] ) 
    )
VAR VisitedChemists = 
    FILTER ( 
        AllChemists, 
        CALCULATE ( 
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Source Data'[CustomerNameFull]  ) 
        ) > 0
    )
VAR RemainingChemists = 
    EXCEPT ( AllChemists, VisitedChemists )
VAR Result = 
    COUNTROWS ( 
        FILTER ( 
            RemainingChemists,
            Table[Chemist] IN VALUES ( Table[Chemist] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but there is nothing like a chemist in my source. All I have a `CustomerNameFull` in which I have my all customers. Here is the link to my [source file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cunwsc3w6ibqqk8/BI%20SAS.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69299604/6854117) related to power-bi?